# PJSUA2 - Recording call audio to wav file

Tags: c++, pjsip

Using PJSUA2 I'm trying to record an incoming call directly to a wav file but can't hear any audio in the wav file.

Code below:

```
void SipCall::onCallMediaState(pj::OnCallMediaStateParam& /*prm*/)
{
    pj::CallInfo call_info = getInfo();
    pj::AudioMedia* audio_media = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < call_info.media.size(); ++i) {
        if (call_info.media[i].type == PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            audio_media = static_cast<pj::AudioMedia*>(getMedia(i));
            break;
        }
    }

     if (audio_media != 0) {
            try {    
                pj::AudioMediaRecorder recorder;
                recorder.createRecorder("file.wav");
                audio_media->startTransmit(recorder);   
                pj_thread_sleep(5000);
                audio_media->stopTransmit(recorder);   
            }  
            catch (pj::Error& err) {
                qWarning("[SipAccount::onIncomingCall] : Failed to record call to %s. Error = %s", "file.wav", err.info().data());    
           }        
      }
 }
```

There's poor documentation on PJSUA2 so does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem because the AudioMediaRecorder object went out of scope just after it was created. If you make it a member of the class the following will work.

```
void SipCall::onCallMediaState(pj::OnCallMediaStateParam& /*prm*/)
{
   pj::CallInfo call_info = getInfo();
   pj::AudioMedia* audio_media = 0;
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < call_info.media.size(); ++i) {
      if (call_info.media[i].type == PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        audio_media = static_cast<pj::AudioMedia*>(getMedia(i));
        break;
      }
   }

   if (audio_media != 0) {
        try {    
            recorder.createRecorder("file.wav");
            audio_media->startTransmit(recorder);   
        }  
        catch (pj::Error& err) {
            qWarning("[SipAccount::onIncomingCall] : Failed to record call to %s. Error = %s", "file.wav", err.info().data());    
       }        
    }
 }
```

Do any necessary cleanup in the onCallState() method below:

```
void SipCall::onCallState(pj::OnCallStateParam& prm)
{
    int i = prm.e.type;
    i = 0;

    pj::CallInfo call_info = getInfo();

    switch (call_info.state) {
       case PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED:
          // Add clean up code here
          delete this;        
          break;
       case PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONFIRMED:                        
          break;
       default:
          break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello dear, can you please let me how to stream sound file at the destination. I am so confused what path should we that file because from http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/media.html I can see there is the possibility of doing same what I need.
what I need to do: I need to play your call is on hold while caller press hold button.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while calling PJ through JNI. In my case I forgot to close the recorder. If you look close in the [documentation](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/media.html#recording-to-wav-file), it says that you can't playback the wav file unless you close the recorder. So after you stop the transmission, do not forget to delete the recorder.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're doing wrong is waiting in `onCallMediaState`'s thread. In order to process the call further this thread has to proceed running. So, you create recorder, wait (while nothing happens, so you record nothing), close recorder, call continues. So nothing has been recorded. It has nothing to do with scope, because in your case recorder had already done his job recording nothing when got out of scope.

Main thing you needed to do is indeed not to wait in `onCallMediaState`'s thread, let the call continue, and destroy the recorder when call is destroyed. For this to happen you need to get recorder declaration out of `SipCall::onCallMediaState`, of course or as you said recorder would get destroyed before it gets its job done.