# PJSUA2 - Recording call to WAV in Windows with Null-Audio

Tags: c++, wav, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm currently starting to work with PJSUA2. I want to develop an SIP client that accepts calls. When it accepts a call, I play a WAV file and record the input to a WAV file as well. PJSIP does not detect my default audio devices, but that's fine since I don't want to use them anyway, so I go for NullAudio via audDevManager().setNullDev().

Here's the code of my call:

```
class MyCall : public Call {
public:
AudioMediaPlayer player;
AudioMediaRecorder recorder;
AudioMediaRecorder recorderVerify;

MyCall(Account &acc, int call_id = PJSUA_INVALID_ID)
: Call(acc, call_id)
{ }

void MyCall::onCallState(OnCallStateParam &prm)
{
    cout << "!!!!!   onCallState is called   !!!!!" << endl;
    CallInfo ci = getInfo();
    cout << "ci.state = " << ci.state << endl;
    if (ci.state == PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
        delete this;
    }
}

void MyCall::onCallMediaState(OnCallMediaStateParam &prm){
    cout << "!!!!!      onCallMediaState is called     !!!!!" << endl;

    try{
        player.createPlayer("Ring02.wav", PJMEDIA_FILE_NO_LOOP);
        recorder.createRecorder("in.wav");
        recorderVerify.createRecorder("test.wav");
        CallInfo ci = getInfo();
        AudioMedia* aud_med = 0;
        // Iterate all the call medias
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < ci.media.size(); i++) {
            cout << "Check audio " << i << endl;
            if (ci.media[i].type==PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO && getMedia(i)) {
                aud_med = static_cast<AudioMedia*>( getMedia(i));
                break;
            }
        }
        if (aud_med != 0){
            cout << "Send stuff to media" << endl;

            // Connect the call audio media to sound device
            AudDevManager& mgr = Endpoint::instance().audDevManager();
            player.startTransmit(*aud_med);
            aud_med->startTransmit(recorder);
            player.startTransmit(recorderVerify);
        }

    } catch (Error& err) {
        cout << "Error when playing: " << err.info() << endl;
    }
}
```

};

I already made the player and recorder member variables based upon [PJSUA2 - Recording call audio to wav file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949357/pjsua2-recording-call-audio-to-wav-file). Now I can correctly play a WAV file to the caller and I also can record my own WAV file via recorderVerify. But the audio from the caller is not recorded, but the generated WAV file is silence instead.

Do I need to initialize something or what did I miss? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Did you ever find out what was wrong?

Comment: Unfotunately not. I didn't get it to run and went on with other projects that didn't involve SIP. But if you have any idea, I would like to return to it and give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

That is just a wild guess.

When PJSUA sends second INVITE request right after first OK was received, which it does in in-dialog mode (you can check that with wireshark), `onCallMediaState` is called second time and, if for some reason parties agreed on some another codec, not that that was the first time, there could be another `getMedia(i)` object, and the first original one could be destroyed. In that case recorder just stops recording and you get WAV one second long.

When `onCallMediaState` is called second time for second INVITE request, you are trying to

```
player.createPlayer("Ring02.wav", PJMEDIA_FILE_NO_LOOP);
recorder.createRecorder("in.wav");
recorderVerify.createRecorder("test.wav");
```

which will throw, because they've been already created. If I am right, your log has to have that error notice. So you don't get to

```
aud_med->startTransmit(recorder);
```

to continue recording, therefore your WAV contains fraction of second long record of a conversation, before session was re-initialized.

Comment: Absolutely correct. It should be green-ticked as answer.